# javascript toggle animation issue

Tags: javascript

I am doing a small javascript animation. this is my code :

```
window.onload = function () {
  var heading = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
  heading.onclick = function () {

    var divHeight = 250;
    var speed = 10;
    var myInterval = 0;

    alert(divHeight);
    slide();

    function slide() {
      if (divHeight == 250) {
        myInterval = setInterval(slideUp, 30);
      } else {
        myInterval = setInterval(slideDwn, 30);
        alert('i am called as slide down')
      }
    }

    function slideUp() {
      var anima = document.getElementById('anima');
      if (divHeight <= 0) {
        divHeight = 0;
        anima.style.height = '0px';
        clearInterval(myInterval);
      } else {
        divHeight -= speed;
        if (divHeight < 0) divHeight = 0;
        anima.style.height = divHeight + 'px';
      }
    }

    function slideDwn() {
      var anima = document.getElementById('anima');
      if (divHeight >= 250) {
        divHeight = 250;
        clearInterval(myInterval);
      } else {
        divHeight += speed;
        anima.style.height = divHeight + 'px';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i am using above code for simple animation. i need to get the result 250 on the first click, as well second click i has to get 0 value. but it showing the 250 with unchanged. but i am assigning the value to set '0', once the div height reached to '0'.

what is the issue with my code? any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've corrected your code a bit (See [working demo](http://jsbin.com/ivoxu3/2))

```
window.onload = function () {

  var heading = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
  var anima = document.getElementById('anima');
  var divHeight = 250;

  heading.onclick = function () {
    var speed = 10;
    var myInterval = 0;

    function slideUp() {
      divHeight -= speed;
      if (divHeight <= 0) {
        divHeight = 0;
        clearInterval(myInterval);
      }
      anima.style.height = divHeight + 'px';
    }

    function slideDwn() {
      divHeight += speed;
      if (divHeight >= 250) {
        divHeight = 250;
        clearInterval(myInterval);
      }
      anima.style.height = divHeight + 'px';
    }

    function slide() {
      console.log(divHeight )
      if (divHeight == 250) {
        myInterval = setInterval(slideUp, 30);
      } else {
        myInterval = setInterval(slideDwn, 30);
      }
    }

    slide();
  }
}​
```

Answer (score 2):

Everytime you click on the div the `divHeight` variable is reset to 250, thus your code never calls `slideDwn`. Moving the `divHeight` declaration outside the event handler should do the trick.

Also, your div wont have the correct size when any of the 2 animations end. You're setting the `divHeight` variable to 250 or 0 correctly, but never actually setting `anima.style.height` after that.

Answer (score 2):

I've rewritten your code into something simpler and lighter. The main difference here is that we're using a single `slide()` function here, and that the height of the div in question is stored in a variable beforehand to ensure that the element slides into the correct position.

Note that this is a very simplistic implementation and assumes that the div carries no padding. (The code uses `ele.clientHeight` and `ele.style.height` interchangeably, which admittedly, is a pretty bad choice, but is done here to keep the code simple)

```
var heading = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    anima = document.getElementById('anima'),
    divHeight = anima.clientHeight,
    speed = 10,
    myInterval = 0,
    animating = false;

function slide(speed, goal) {
    if(Math.abs(anima.clientHeight - goal) <= speed){
        anima.style.height = goal + 'px';
        animating = false;
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    } else if(anima.clientHeight - goal > 0){
        anima.style.height = (anima.clientHeight - speed) + 'px';
    } else {
        anima.style.height = (anima.clientHeight + speed) + 'px';
    }
}

heading.onclick = function() {
    if(!animating) {
        animating = true;
        var goal = (anima.clientHeight >= divHeight) ? 0 : divHeight;
        myInterval = setInterval(slide, 13, speed, goal);
    }
}
```

See http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/dWJgG/2/ for a simple demo.

Comment: can you explain me what is : myInterval = setInterval(slide, 13, 10, goal); ? you have used the 13, 10..?

Comment: @3gweb `setInterval` can take a variable amount of arguments. The first would be the function, the second the interval between which the function will be called, and anything after that will be passed to the function. So by passing in `speed` (not 10, my mistake) and `goal`, we're basically passing the two variables to the function when it runs.

Comment: good. thank you. and final doubt is why you are animating boolean? you are using that to change false to true and ture to false. without the toggle it self it work fine right? then why you use this?

Comment: @3gweb The `animating` boolean is to prevent multiple animation from happening at once, because if that happens, `myInterval` will be overwritten, and the previous interval can never be cleared, so we need to check that variable to stop it from happening

Comment: good. i agree. your code is perfect. you are doing well. keep it up. if you have twitter id, or blog let me know. it may help me to update my self by your thoughts.

Comment: @3gwebtrain Nah, I won't do that if I were you :P There are many many other programmer better than myself on Stack Overflow. You should follow them instead. And the code is far from perfect - the main caveat I wrote about in the answer is not insignificant if you were to actually use this code.